# Why does my code fail with "Marker location must be assigned when added directly to map"?

Tags: python, folium

This my code

```py
import folium

map = folium.Map(Location=[38.58, -99.09],zoom_start=6,tiles='Stamen Terrain')

fg = folium.FeatureGroup(name='My Map')

fg.add_child(folium.Marker(Location=[38.2, -99.1],popup="Hi I am a Marker",icon=folium.Icon(color="green")))

map.add_child(fg)

map.save('Map1.html')
```

This fails with a traceback:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:/Users/Godfrey Baguma/Desktop/Mapping/main.py", line 14, in <module>
    map.save('Map1.html')
  File "C:\Users\Godfrey Baguma\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\branca\element.py", line 167, 
in save
    html = root.render(**kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\Godfrey Baguma\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\branca\element.py", line 319, 
in render
    child.render(**kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\Godfrey Baguma\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\folium\folium.py", line 368, in render
    super(Map, self).render(**kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\Godfrey Baguma\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\folium\elements.py", line 21, 
in render
PS C:\Users\Godfrey Baguma\Desktop\Mapping> & "C:/Users/Godfrey Baguma/AppData/Local/Programs/Python/Python38-32/python.exe" "c:/Users/Godfrey Baguma/Desktop/Mapping/main2.py"
2
PS C:\Users\Godfrey Baguma\Desktop\Mapping> & "C:/Users/Godfrey Baguma/AppData/Local/Programs/Python/Python38-32/python.exe" "c:/Users/Godfrey Baguma/Desktop/Mapping/main.py"
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:/Users/Godfrey Baguma/Desktop/Mapping/main.py", line 14, in <module>
    map.save('Map1.html')
  File "C:\Users\Godfrey Baguma\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\branca\element.py", line 167, 
in save
    html = root.render(**kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\Godfrey Baguma\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\branca\element.py", line 319, 
in render
    child.render(**kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\Godfrey Baguma\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\folium\folium.py", line 368, in render
    super(Map, self).render(**kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\Godfrey Baguma\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\folium\elements.py", line 21, 
in render
    super().render(**kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\Godfrey Baguma\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\branca\element.py", line 643, 
in render
    element.render(**kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\Godfrey Baguma\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\branca\element.py", line 643, 
in render
    element.render(**kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\Godfrey Baguma\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\folium\map.py", line 302, in render
    raise ValueError("{} location must be assigned when added directly to map.".format(self._name))
ValueError: Marker location must be assigned when added directly to map.
```

Answer (score 1):

The reason for the error may be that you are using the function name map. Rewrite it and run it, and it will display correctly.

```
import folium

m = folium.Map(location=[38.58, -99.09],zoom_start=6)

fg = folium.FeatureGroup(name='My Map')
fg.add_child(folium.Marker(location=[38.2, -99.1],popup="Hi I am a Marker",icon=folium.Icon(color="green")))

m.add_child(fg)
m
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Error :
ValueError: Marker location must be assigned when added directly to map.

### Solution:

It clearly indicate that the location value is not assigned .
It expect "location" instead of "Location"

with this change it will run as expected.

Thanks,